# NTFS folders get empty if not accesses for long time

Tags: ntfs

For many years, I've noted this issue. I have practice of keeping all files in a different drives that are of no use currently. These files are stored as a record for future use or references. Many times they are not access for months or years.

Files get missing from sub-folders or sub-sub folders if the folders are not accessed for more than year or many months. Random folder give such behavior. If I miss to recheck them, again some other folders get empty.

Note:My machine is not virus infected. Not rootkit infected. Using Windows 10 Pro and its security solution.

Any guidance to identify problem will be appreciated.

Many files are lost and few of them important files. Seeing this problem since 2010, but mostly ignored as I'd copies on backup drives. But this time, I missed to get the backup done and lost many files.

Comment: Scan disk is not finding any issues.

Comment: The drives where this happen is secondary drive with 2 partitions. The drive is changed in 2013. Noting this as the issue occurred even in previous drives too.